# How to write Arquillian tests for JSF classes

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to perform arquillian tests on a data model rooted in the JSF API. I am getting this error:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.046 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(mypackage.GenericLazyModelTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native 
or abstract in class file javax/faces/model/DataModel
```

Simple arquillian tests, not involving JSF, but JPA and EJB APIs run fine.
Researching the web suggests that a common reason for this is using sun's stub EE APIs as described [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode) and [here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/trouble_with_crippled_java_ee).

I am definitely not using them. Here is the dependency part of my `pom`:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
          <version>${javaee6.with.tools.version}</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
  <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have also tried to use the internal JBoss JSF API for the tests with no effect on the error:

```
 <dependency> 
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId> 
   <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId> 
   <version>2.0.0.Beta1</version> 
   <scope>test</scope> 
 </dependency>
```

My model is derived from the primefaces `LazyDataModel`

```
public class GenericLazyModel<T> extends LazyDataModel<T>
```

`LazyDataModel` in turn is derived from the `javax.faces.model.DataModel`

```
public abstract class LazyDataModel<T> extends DataModel<T> implements SelectableDataModel<T>, Serializable
```

The test is mostly empty, I am requsting an injection of my model and check for `null`:

**EDIT** the ShrinkWrap initialization now includes a `faces-config.xml`, as proposed by stefanglase. Did not change the error output though.

```
   @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class GenericLazyModelTest {

        @Deployment
        public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {

          return ShrinkWrap
            .create(WebArchive.class, "genericLazyModelTest.war")
                .addClasses(GenericLazyModel.class, Submitter.class, SubmitterPK.class,
                            Ordering.class)
                .addClasses(GenericDao.class, Resources.class)
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset("<faces-config version=\"2.0\"/>"), "faces-config.xml")                            
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        }

        @Inject
        GenericLazyModel<Submitter> model;

        @Before
        public void before() {
            Assert.assertNotNull(model);
            model.setKlazz(Submitter.class);
        }
```

I am running this on Jboss 7.1.0.Final.
Any ideas on what could be the issue and how to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `faces-config.xml` in your Deployment. The Java EE 6 specification requires a `faces-config.xml` descriptor to be present in your `WEB-INF`-directory to trigger JSF.

Unlike `beans.xml` which you already included the `faces-config.xml` descriptor cannot be an empty file. It must contain at least the root node and the version attribute to specify the JSF version in use.

So you need to add the following code to your ShrinkWrap builder:

```
.addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset("<faces-config version=\"2.0\"/>"), "faces-config.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. It may have saved me from more issues down the road, but unfortunately it had no influence on the ClassFormatError. I'll edit the question to include the faces-config